# How to put a layout over a YouTube player while it is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I’m trying to put a layer over a YouTube player in fullscreen mode. I’ve tried putting a layout over YouTube through the xml but it isn’t visible when YouTube is in fullsreen mode. Is there a way I can put a custom button or layout over the YouTube player in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put a layer on top of Youtube Player. Whenever an overlay is detected, the youtube playback stops playing. [For more info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView)

> Note that while videos are playing, this View has a minimum size of 200x110 dp. If you make the view any smaller, videos will automatically stop playing. Also, it is not permitted to overlay the view with other views while a video is playing.

You can put a layout outside the player or use [Overlay ActionBar](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Overlay_ActionBar_Demo)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: But can't we use player.setControlFlags(YoutubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT)?